# Is sha256 a good function to derive 256 bit keys from a secret of sufficient length and entropy?

Tags: hash, key-generation

Assuming I have a secret key of sufficient length and entropy (I get to decide the length and have a good random source).

I would like to generate 256 length keys by hashing the root key with the name of each key, ex:

```
key1 = sha256(rootKey +"key1") 
key2 = sha256(rootKey +"key2") 
...
keyN = sha256(rootKey +"keyN")
```

Is the sha256 hash a good choice ?

If yes, what length should the root secret be ? I'm thinking 256 bit is pretty good, but it wouldn't cost much to make it bigger...

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the input key is sufficiently entropic by itself, and both the input key and the identifier have a fixed length, you can safely use SHA-256 to derive extra keys. A fixed length is required to avoid [length extension attacks](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/3978/54184) which affect all non-truncated Merkle–Damgård hashes, including SHA-256. A safer way to do this, however, is to use [HMAC for key derivation](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/79173/106285), which makes this scheme more flexible so length extension attacks are not a worry. When using HMAC, the input key is used as the HMAC key, and the identifier is the message to be hashed. You can also use a standard KDF such as [HKDF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5869).

Comment: thanks, how can the length extension attack be applicable in this context, since there is no message siguature validation involved ?

Comment: @MaxL. Given one identifier, an attacker can calculate what the derived key would be for another identifier (with that identifier having certain limitations, in particular being a concatenation of the first identifier, MD padding material, and an arbitrary suffix). That would violate the security assumptions of a good KDF. If the identifier and input key are both fixed-length, then this attack is not applicable.